# Selecting multiple columns/fields in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

Basically, there is an attribute table and translation table - many translations for one attribute.

I need to select id and value from translation for each attribute in a specified language, even if there is no translation record in that language. Either I am missing some join technique or join (without involving language table) is not working here since the following do not return attributes with non-existing translations in the specified language.

```
select a.attribute, at.id, at.translation 
from attribute a left join attributeTranslation at on a.id=at.attribute
where al.language=1;
```

So I am using subqueries like this, problem here is making two subqueries to the same table with the same parameters (feels like performance drain unless MySQL groups those, which I doubt since it makes you do many similar subqueries)

```
select attribute, 
(select id from attributeTranslation where attribute=a.id and language=1),
(select translation from attributeTranslation where attribute=a.id and language=1), 
from attribute a;
```

I would like to be able to get id and translation from one query, so I concat columns and get the id from string later, which is at least making single subquery but still not looking right.

```
select attribute,
(select concat(id,';',title)
    from offerAttribute_language 
    where offerAttribute=a.id and _language=1
)
from offerAttribute a
```

So the question part.
Is there a way to get multiple columns from a single subquery or should I use two subqueries (MySQL is smart enough to group them?) or is joining the following way to go:

[[attribute to language] to translation] (joining 3 tables seems like a worse performance than subquery).

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  The knack you need is the concept that there are two ways of getting tables out of the table server.  One way is ..

```
FROM TABLE A
```

The other way is

```
FROM (SELECT col as name1, col2 as name2 FROM ...) B
```

Notice that the select clause and the parentheses around it *are* a table, a virtual table.

So, using your second code example (I am guessing at the columns you are hoping to retrieve here):

```
SELECT a.attr, b.id, b.trans, b.lang
FROM attribute a
JOIN (
 SELECT at.id AS id, at.translation AS trans, at.language AS lang, a.attribute
 FROM attributeTranslation at
) b ON (a.id = b.attribute AND b.lang = 1)
```

Notice that your real table `attribute` is the first table in this join, and that this virtual table I've called `b` is the second table.

This technique comes in especially handy when the virtual table is a summary table of some kind.  e.g.

```
SELECT a.attr, b.id, b.trans, b.lang, c.langcount
FROM attribute a
JOIN (
 SELECT at.id AS id, at.translation AS trans, at.language AS lang, at.attribute
 FROM attributeTranslation at
) b ON (a.id = b.attribute AND b.lang = 1)
JOIN (
 SELECT count(*) AS langcount,  at.attribute
 FROM attributeTranslation at
 GROUP BY at.attribute
) c ON (a.id = c.attribute)
```

See how that goes? You've generated a virtual table `c` containing two columns, joined it to the other two, used one of the columns for the `ON` clause, and returned the other as a column in your result set.

Comment: SELECT a.attribute, b.id, b.translation
FROM attribute a left JOIN (SELECT id, translation, attribute FROM translation where _language=1) b
on a.id=b.attribute is what i got working for me, thanks :)

Comment: @Martin, you can just join for that; no need for virtual tables. SELECT a.a, tr.id, tr.translation FROM attribute a LEFT JOIN translation tr ON a.id=tr.attribute WHERE tr.language=1

Comment: I mentioned, probably didn't point out enough, that some records do not have translations, so if i say language=1 and there is no translation, i miss attribute record.

Comment: @O.Jones - This will work but if the attributeTranslation table is large, it can be a lot less efficient than the subquery used in the OP's question since it the virtual table doesn't benefit from the attribute_id index (assuming there is one).  I'd be curious to know if there is a way to achieve building a virtual table but restricting it by column from table a.  So far I've been stuck with OP's method