# MySQL - WHERE clause + JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've got the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT user_id, score, time 
FROM tests_1 T
WHERE T.score = (
SELECT MAX(T2.score)
FROM tests_1 T2
WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
)
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC;
```

How do I add the 'username' column from the 'users' table ON users.user_id = tests_1.user_id?

Comment: First off, it looks like you are missing a `FROM tests_1 T` on line 2 of your code snippet. Is that correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple columns/fields in MySQL subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686271/selecting-multiple-columns-fields-in-mysql-subquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.user_id, U.username, T.score, T.time 
FROM tests_1 T
JOIN users U on U.user_id = T.user_id
WHERE T.score = (
SELECT MAX(T2.score)
FROM tests_1 T2
WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
)
ORDER BY T.score DESC, T.time ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join it.

```
SELECT T.user_id, T.score, T.time, u.username
FROM tests_1 T
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = T.user_id
WHERE T.score = (
SELECT MAX(T2.score)
FROM tests_1 T2
WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
)
ORDER BY T.score DESC, T.time ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, score, time, U.username
FROM tests_1 T JOIN users U
    ON T.user_id = U.user_id
WHERE T.score = (
    SELECT MAX(T2.score)
    FROM tests_1 T2
    WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
)
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC;
```

Comment: You're comparins a column to itself in the `ON` clause. One of them should be `U`.