# how can i convert inner join into a subquery?

Tags: mysql

im trying to convert my inner join into a subquery but im not sure how, here is my code

```
select passenger.Email, passenger.First_Name, passenger.Last_Name, passenger.Mobile_Number,
       flight.Email, flight.Departure_Airport, flight.Departure_Date
from passenger
inner join flight on passenger.Email = flight.Email
where flight.Departure_Airport = 'jfk' 
and  flight.Departure_Date >= '2021-06-30';
```

can anyone explain how to do this or put me in the right direction?

Comment: *im trying to convert my inner join into a subquery* What is the goal?

Comment: do you want to change the results somehow?  there is no good way to use subqueries to do the same thing this query does

Comment: in terms of the goal i need to display departures with jfk and dates after 6/30/2021, im pretty sure the best way to do this is like how i did but i wanted to know how would you do it in a subquery way or if its even possible.

Comment: When using in sub-query, you usually just get values from one column back, so it could be `where passenger.Email IN (select Email from flight ...)` but that ruins your result set, since then you will not get the other values from the flight table. Unless you want to join to a sub-query. See [Selecting multiple columns/fields in MySQL subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686271/selecting-multiple-columns-fields-in-mysql-subquery) for how to do that. I'd stick to the query you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a subquery that has the `WHERE` clause in it, and join with that.

```
select passenger.Email, passenger.First_Name, passenger.Last_Name, passenger.Mobile_Number,
       flight.Email, flight.Departure_Airport, flight.Departure_Date
from passenger
inner join (
    SELECT flight.Email, flight.Departure_Airport, flight.Departure_Date
    FROM flight
    where flight.Departure_Airport = 'jfk' 
    and  flight.Departure_Date >= '2021-06-30'
) AS flight on passenger.Email = flight.Email
```

MySQL should implement both queries the same.

Comment: How is this post then not a duplicate of the post I linked in the comment on the Question?

Comment: @Scratte I missed your comment and didn't have a duplicate in my list.

Comment: There's no time like the present. I'm sure you have a gold-hammer in there somewhere ;)